# Отправка файл через telegram http api из байтовой переменной

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram

Пытаюсь отправить текстовый файл через HTTP-API Telegram.
Проблема -  файл приходит, имя файла 'document' и без расширения, что не позволяет открыт его одним кликом.
Делаю так:

```
report_message = "some text" # текстовое содержимое отправляемого файла
files = {'document': bytes(report_message , "UTF-8")}
report_response = requests.post(f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{bot_api_token}/sendDocument",
                                  data={'chat_id': chat_id}, files=files)
```

При изменении ключа 'document' - ответ 400.
Если сохранить файл и после этого открыть его для чтения, то всё норм и имя файла корректное, однако сохранять и перечитывать ради указания имени файла считаю некошерным.
Как явно указать имя для отправляемого файла, без лишних операций?

Comment: Читайте в документации requests, как указывать имя файла https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file

Comment: Работает, однако. Спасибо.